# Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgIf -> ViewContainerRef]: After upgrading angular 6 to 7

Tags: angular, angular7

After a shared module which i build in different project, compiled into install-able npm module. I then am able to use my module across other angular projects. The shareable components where in angular 6 before and so are my previous projects. I decided to upgrade my project to angular 7 today. When i start the project, it works fine and as expected.

However, after i package it into npm install-able and install it in the other projects, my project failed with

> RROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgIf -> ViewContainerRef]: 
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NgIf -> ViewContainerRef]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for ViewContainerRef!

I then upgraded the embedding project modules to match the shareable project, yet it persist. I noticed that all the directives exposed by `commonModule` are breaking with the error above. The shareable project however, works independently. The installed components just doesn't seem to recognize `commonModule` even though it exist. Below is how i use the components in my project.

```
import { LoaderModule } from "my-angular-components/dist/loader";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        LoaderModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: true })
    ],
    declarations: [],
    ...
})
```

And my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "es7",
            "es2015",
            "dom"
        ],
        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noEmitHelpers": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "outDir": "lib",
        "rootDir": ".",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "target": "es5",
    }
```

Is there any breaking change in angular 7 that is breaking the `commonModule` ? This works if i revert both of them to angular 6 but not 7. project works also independently without having another components installed as a module. Please, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

using the --aot or --preserve-symlinks flag on ng serve probably solves this issue